# Different error message when unittest.assertRaisesRegex is called as a context manager

Tags: python, exception, python-unittest

**Context (can be skipped, the real question comes after)**

The whole thing is un-important but I'm on an investigation that got me more and more confused.

A pet project of mine has some logic relying on Python exceptions message (and not just the type). As it is very fragile, I make sure I have things running of most Python versions I can on Travis.

Recently, I realised that the piece of code `set.add(0)` leads to an exception whose message is expected to be something along the lines of:

> descriptor 'add' requires a 'set' object but received a 'int'

However, on some versions of Python 3.7+, things started to look different in a few test cases. Apparently the message is more like:

> "descriptor 'add' for 'set' objects doesn't apply to 'int' object"

Just because I wanted to be sure this was intended by the Python developers, I wanted to find the exact commit changing this relying on some `git bisect` magic and started to look for a minimalistic way to reproduce this issue. Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce this behavior locally and one thing leading to another I went down the rabbit hole and ended with many mysteries, one of them involving [`unittest.assertRaisesRegex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegex).

**Unexpected `unittest.assertRaisesRegex` behavior**

I wrote the following tests which look surprisingly similar to the `unittest.assertRaisesRegex` examples from the doc - one test providing a callable and corresponding arguments, another test relying on a context manager:

```
    DESCRIPT_REQUIRES_TYPE_RE = r"descriptor '\w+' requires a 'set' object but received a 'int'"

    ...

    def test_assertRaisesRegex(self):
        self.assertRaisesRegex(TypeError, DESCRIPT_REQUIRES_TYPE_RE, set.add, 0)

    def test_assertRaisesRegex_contextman(self):
        with self.assertRaisesRegex(TypeError, DESCRIPT_REQUIRES_TYPE_RE):
            set.add(0)
```

I'd expect both of them to have the exact same behavior but they don't.

(Versions numbers are retrieved with `python -VV` and `python -c "import sys; print(sys._git)"`)

- On some versions, both tests pass:

  - Python 3.6 and before
  - Python 3.7.0a4+ (heads/master:4666ec5, Jan 26 2018, 04:14:24)  - [GCC 4.8.4] - ('CPython', 'heads/master', '4666ec5'))
- On some versions, both tests fail:

  - Python 3.8.0a1+ (heads/master:8a03ff2, Feb  9 2019, 07:30:26) 
    [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] - ('CPython', 'heads/master', '8a03ff2')
- On some versions, only `test_assertRaisesRegex_contextman` fails which is what I find confusing:

  - Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec  5 2018, 18:09:53) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] - ('CPython', '', '')
  - Python 3.7.2+ (heads/3.7:3fcfef3, Feb  9 2019, 07:30:09) 
    [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] - ('CPython', 'heads/3.7', '3fcfef3')

When they happen, the failures look like:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_assertRaisesRegex (didyoumean_sugg_tests.SetAddIntRegexpTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: descriptor 'add' for 'set' objects doesn't apply to 'int' object
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/build/.../didyoumean_sugg_tests.py", line 19, in test_assertRaisesRegex
    self.assertRaisesRegex(TypeError, DESCRIPT_REQUIRES_TYPE_RE, set.add, 0)
AssertionError: "descriptor '\w+' requires a 'set' object but received a 'int'" does not match "descriptor 'add' for 'set' objects doesn't apply to 'int' object"
```

and

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_assertRaisesRegex_contextman (didyoumean_sugg_tests.SetAddIntRegexpTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: descriptor 'add' for 'set' objects doesn't apply to 'int' object
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/build/.../didyoumean/didyoumean_sugg_tests.py", line 23, in test_assertRaisesRegex_contextman
    set.add(0)
AssertionError: "descriptor '\w+' requires a 'set' object but received a 'int'" does not match "descriptor 'add' for 'set' objects doesn't apply to 'int' object"
```

Why would these 2 similar looking tests have different behavior ?

**Additional points that get me confused**

- I couldn't reproduce the issue locally on cpython code I'd checkout and build (even using the correct SHA1)
- on Travis, running `python -c "set.add(0)"` always leads to the same (expected) string:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'add' requires a 'set' object but received a 'int'
```

**Status so far**

Everything probably boils down a simple detail I am missing but I am out of clue at the moment. Any suggestion is welcome. I'm happy to trigger more Travis builds if more data is required.

Comment: I've opened a bug on the Python tracker: https://bugs.python.org/issue35965 .

Comment: It looks like this is most probably a coverage bug. Ticket to be opened.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an expected behavior anyway. A coverage ticket is to be opened.

Comment: Opened another Python bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue36026 .